# TCL sort list/variable entries by date

Tags: tcl

I have a variable that contains dates and data on each line, and wanted to know how to sort by date? I've tried lsort after splitting the variable, but that only sorts by the day (date format DD/MM/YYYY).

eg the variable has the following:

```
01/11/2020,$239,Sandy 
05/12/2019,$19,Boe 
14/09/2022,$22,Fred 
06/02/2021,$55,Andrew 
...etc...
```

I've used [lsort -unique -index 0 [split $mylist "\n"]], but that only sorts by the day (DD), not the whole date (DD/MM/YYYY)

ie

```
01/11/2020,$239,Sandy 
05/12/2019,$19,Boe 
06/02/2021,$55,Andrew 
14/09/2022,$22,Fred 
...etc.
```

needs to sort it by date

```
05/12/2019,$19,Boe 
01/11/2020,$239,Sandy 
06/02/2021,$55,Andrew 
14/09/2022,$22,Fred 
...etc
```

**UPDATE/ADDITIONAL**:

The code to load the data is as follows:

```
set fr [open "${currentdir}/test.csv" r]
set mylist [read $fr]
close $fr
```

The file is just a text file and has many lines of of data, each line starting with a date column (date format can be either 22/01/2019, 01/03/2019, 1/3/2019 - (ie <day 1-2 digits>/<month 1-2 digits>/<year 4 digits>). The other columns can have any data, spaces, values, $dollars, etc. but they all have the same number of elements (ie 12 columns)

test.csv example file

```
19/12/2008,Some test values,1,Some other test values,1,43.90050622
16/12/2008,Some test values,2,Some other test values,2,69.0326854
11/12/2008,Some test values,3,Some other test values,3,20.03514637
10/12/2008,Some test values,4,Some other test values,4,31.89534427
10/12/2008,Some test values,5,Some other test values,5,45.16309485
9/12/2008,Some test values,6,Some other test values,6,80.15651004
27/11/2008,Some test values,7,Some other test values,7,14.68529885
27/11/2008,Some test values,8,Some other test values,8,37.59341648
25/11/2008,Some test values,9,Some other test values,9,44.36159437
25/11/2008,Some test values,10,Some other test values,10,44.960349
```

Comment: Using the ISO8601 YYYY-mm-dd date format will make this a lot easier.

Comment: `set mylist [read $fr]` is insufficient: You'll get records like `{2008,Some} {test} {values,1,Some} {other} {test} {values,1,43.90050622}` in `$mylist`. Use `set mylist [split [read -nonewline $fr] \n]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
set l {01/11/2020,$239,Sandy
05/12/2019,$19,Boe
14/09/2022,$22,Fred
06/02/2021,$55,Andrew
}
```

then a Schwartzian transform ("decorate-sort-undecorate") could look like

```
set decorated [lmap line $l {
    list $line [string cat [string range $line 6 9] \
                           [string range $line 3 4] \
                           [string range $line 0 1] ]
}]
set sorted [lsort -index 1 $decorated]
set undecorated [lmap item $sorted {lindex $item 0}]

# => {05/12/2019,$19,Boe} {01/11/2020,$239,Sandy} {06/02/2021,$55,Andrew} {14/09/2022,$22,Fred}
```

---

please see my comment about properly reading the file into records.

---

If your date format doesn't always use 2-digit days or months, then it gets a little more complicated. Fix how the file gets generated, or use:

```
set f [open test.csv]
set l [split [read -nonewline $f] \n]
close $f

set decorated [lmap line $l {
    set date [lindex [split $line ,] 0]
    lassign [split $date /] d m y
    set iso_date [format "%4d%02d%02d" $y $m $d]
    list $line $iso_date
}]

puts [join $decorated \n]
```

```
{19/12/2008,Some test values,1,Some other test values,1,43.90050622} 20081219
{16/12/2008,Some test values,2,Some other test values,2,69.0326854} 20081216
{11/12/2008,Some test values,3,Some other test values,3,20.03514637} 20081211
{10/12/2008,Some test values,4,Some other test values,4,31.89534427} 20081210
{10/12/2008,Some test values,5,Some other test values,5,45.16309485} 20081210
{9/12/2008,Some test values,6,Some other test values,6,80.15651004} 20081209
{27/11/2008,Some test values,7,Some other test values,7,14.68529885} 20081127
{27/11/2008,Some test values,8,Some other test values,8,37.59341648} 20081127
{25/11/2008,Some test values,9,Some other test values,9,44.36159437} 20081125
{25/11/2008,Some test values,10,Some other test values,10,44.960349} 20081125
```

continuing

```
set sorted [lsort -index 1 $decorated]
set undecorated [lmap item $sorted {lindex $item 0}]
puts [join $undecorated \n]
```

```
25/11/2008,Some test values,9,Some other test values,9,44.36159437
25/11/2008,Some test values,10,Some other test values,10,44.960349
27/11/2008,Some test values,7,Some other test values,7,14.68529885
27/11/2008,Some test values,8,Some other test values,8,37.59341648
9/12/2008,Some test values,6,Some other test values,6,80.15651004
10/12/2008,Some test values,4,Some other test values,4,31.89534427
10/12/2008,Some test values,5,Some other test values,5,45.16309485
11/12/2008,Some test values,3,Some other test values,3,20.03514637
16/12/2008,Some test values,2,Some other test values,2,69.0326854
19/12/2008,Some test values,1,Some other test values,1,43.90050622
```

Comment: Simple date conversion comparison - faster than the other solution  on small sample data was 1701 Vs 539517 microseconds.. I have over 14million lines to sort so this was faster.

Comment: There seems to be a possible issue if the 2nd coloum does not start with $ for some reason (eg its text or just a numner). Could you walk through/explain each step?

Comment: What kind of issue? Is it not sorting correctly? Does the "undecorated" list not maintain the original lines?

Comment: This also breaks when there is a space in one of the columns data (eg 05/12/2019,$19,Boe Smith,North Wing).

Comment: I believe that breakage happens before my code. How do you transform the input file into a list?

Comment: Issue 1 - using data: 19/12/2008,Test,dddd,234\n
16/12/2008,Test,dddd,234\n
11/12/2008,Test,dddd,234\n...etc....gives result $undecorated "/10/2008,Test,dddd,234 3/11/2008,Test,dddd,234 9/12/2008,Test,dddd,234 3/07/2008,Test,dddd,234 5/11/2009,Test,..etc"

Comment: The whole data is loaded from a text file into a single variable - set fr [open "${currentdir}/test.csv" r]
set mylist [read $fr]
close $fr....
it works fine when $ is used but when there is no $, it breaks as above comment. The variable is just a series of lines (\n) with <date>,<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,etc...<\n as newline><date>,<data1>,<data2>,<data3>,etc...

Comment: Would be helpful to edit the question with further details: the actual code used to read the file, the (formatted) input and output lines at issue, etc

Answer (score 3):

First define a proc that can be used with the `lsort -command` option.  Such a proc requires two arguments and must return -1, 0 or 1.

This proc uses `clock scan` to convert your string to a clock value that can be sorted.

```
proc sort_by_date {a b} {
    set date_a [lindex [split $a ","] 0]
    set date_b [lindex [split $b ","] 0]

    set clock_a [clock scan $date_a -format "%m/%d/%Y"]
    set clock_b [clock scan $date_b -format "%m/%d/%Y"]

    if {$clock_a < $clock_b} {
        return -1
    } elseif {$clock_a > $clock_b} {
        return 1
    } else {
        return [string compare $a $b]
    }
}
```

The result of `clock scan` for each date is in the Linux epoch format (https://www.epochconverter.com/)

```
1578729600
1557644400
1675929600
1622617200
```

These are easily sortable now.

```
> lsort -command sort_by_date $lines
05/12/2019,$19,Boe
01/11/2020,$239,Sandy
06/02/2021,$55,Andrew
14/09/2022,$22,Fred
```

A faster implementation would avoid `clock scan`, because you don't really care about the seconds.

Using Glenn's conversion method, but inside the proc:

```
proc sort_by_date {a b} {
    set date_a [string cat [string range $a 6 9] [string range $a 3 4] [string range $a 0 1] ]
    set date_b [string cat [string range $b 6 9] [string range $b 3 4] [string range $b 0 1] ]

    return [string compare $date_a $date_b]
}
```

Comment: The other thing you could have done is to transform the dates into julian day numbers. They're often a better choice for pure dates.

Comment: What's the standard way to do that?

Comment: Thanks, nice and clean. Microseconds to execute sample data was 539517 Vs 1701 for other suggested solution. I suspect the proc approach and if checks added more time to execute (i have over 14milion lines to sort).

Comment: This breaks if there is a space in any of the data/columns (eg 05/12/2019,$19,Boe Smith,North Wing).

Comment: I updated my answer with a more minimal approach.   You will need to modify the proc as needed to handle excess white space though.